# Ubuntu 18.04 inverted colors in PDF print after reinstalling libgs9-common package

Tags: 18.04, printing, pdf, colors, ghostscript

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04, CUPS would no longer print PDFs. I checked `/var/log/cups/error.log` and discovered these error messages:

```
/base/gsicc_manage.c:1244: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_gray.icc 
D [30/Oct/2018:10:12:06 +0100] [Job 3430] | ./base/gsicc_manage.c:2261: gsicc_init_iccmanager(): cannot find default icc profile
D [30/Oct/2018:10:12:06 +0100] [Job 3430] ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1244: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_rgb.icc
```

I thought it may be a problem with symlinks, and while troubleshooting ghostscript I tried reinstalling the `libgs9-common` package

Now I can print again, but all the colors are inverted. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: This has been reported as a bug, please indicate that it affects you in order to boost its priority: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1560286